# Exiting a program ..alternative (C Language)

Tags: c

This is the code I use for a list of options in my program.

Of course, if the numbers of options grows (more than 9) I have to change the while condition taking a different number.

What I'd like to avoid is to resort to a two digit number.

How could I make the user to press the 'ESC' key to exit the program? or any other key or different solution if any available....

```
   while (option < 9)
    {
    system("clear");

            printf("+------------------------------------------+\n");
            printf("|   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx             |\n");
            printf("+------------------------------------------+\n");
            printf("                                        \n");
            printf("********************************************\n");
            printf("|         Operations                   |\n");
            printf("********************************************\n");
            printf("| 1) Option 1                              |\n");
            printf("| 2) Option 2                              |\n");
            printf("| 3) Option 3                              |\n");
            printf("| 9) EXIT                                  |\n");
            printf("+------------------------------------------+\n");

            printf("Option -->: ");
            scanf("%d", &option);

            if (option==1) func1(conn);
            if (option==2) func2(conn);
            if (option==3) func3(conn);
    } 
            mysql_close (conn);

        system("clear");

        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Thanks Mauro

Answer (score 1):

Read a char instead of an int (or better yet, a key press). Then if the so read char is between `'0'` and `'9'` turn it into an integer and use it as option; otherwise make your loop terminate, return from main, call exit or whatever way you prefer to end execution.

Comment: thanks..How do I read a key press in C?...my purpose is to make a portable program..

Comment: @Mauro No, you can't read an ESC portable in strictly conforming C. Have a look at the (portable) ncurses-library.

Comment: @user411313: Luckily he stated in his question that any other key would do.